# Ldap Error 500 Issue

Tags: php, ldap

I'm trying to migrate a site from a Windows XP/PHP5.2.0/MySQL5.5.8 configuration to a Windows Server 2008/PHP5.3.8/MySQL5.5.8 one.

The database and the index.php page are working fine. But for the login i am using a ldap_connect to get through. And this is when i get the Error 500.

When i do the usual `phpinfo();` i see that the ldap module is not loaded. Fine i just have to edit my `php.ini` file, unquote `extension_dir = "ext"` and add `extension=php_ldap.dll` to it.

But as i am restart my Apache server it crashes adding this entry to the Event journal (i translated it myself since it was in french) :

```
Name of the failing application httpd.exe, version : 2.2.21.0, timestamp : 0x4e6a3015
Name of the failing module : php5ts.dll, version : 5.3.4.0, timestamp : 0x4d014bae
Exception Code : 0xc0000005
Error offset : 0x000e837c
Failling Process ID : 0x7b8
Starting time of failing application : 0x01ccd1405a22cca2
Path to the faulty application : C:\dev\tools\Apache2.2\bin\httpd.exe
Path to the faulty module: C:\dev\tools\PHP\php5ts.dll
Report ID : fa7f9585-3d37-11e1-84f3-005056bf005e
```

And i can't find a way to fix that, importing the PHP versions from my Windows XP and getting the latest 5.3.9 or older 5.2.0, nothing seems to work.

I have seen somewhere that on Windows the php.ini is in the C:\WINDOWS folder, i put a copy in there but php doesn't seem to use it since it always uses the modifications i put in the php.ini in the PHP folder.

Comment: Have you verified a) that the file `php_ldap.dll` exists in the `ext` directory and b) that the `ext` dir is in your `%PATH%`?

Answer (score 3):

It works for me too

There seems to be a bug somewhere. If you are experiencing this on Win 7 64 bit then try installing `apache` addon version 2.2.9 and php addon version 5.3.1 and switching to those in WAMP and then activating the CURL extension.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i had some corrupted distribution or something but i figured it out by downloading another latest PHP distribution from php.net and it worked.

Yes i had the extension php_ldap.dll in both my ext and /PHP/ directories, my %PATH% was correctly setup and both php.ini in C:\Windows and the /PHP/ directories were correctly configured.

I think php_ldap.dll must have been corrupted though i tried with several PHP versions.